# How to change background color and set bar colors based on conditional formatting in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This is the chart format I need to make from VBA for my personal data points :

[Chart Style Needed Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5or1a.png)

I do not know how to change the background color to blue, Axis title colors and line colors to white and I need to set the bar colors based on the values as shown as the image above. So if the value of the bar is 2.9 it would be red, if it is 3.5 it would be gold, and if it is more than 4, it will be green.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub CreateBarChart()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$4:$F$5")
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = False
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = False
    ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Delete
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0"
                
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the macro recorder to capture the events while you make those changes, then try using the generated code as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Define active chart:

```
Dim c As Chart
Set c = ActiveChart
```

To color the background use:     `c.ChartArea.Interior.Color = vbBlue`

To color the points based on value, you can define the series as an array and then evaluate each value in the array:

```
seriesarray = c.SeriesCollection(1).Values      'define array
For i = 1 To UBound(seriesarray)      'for each value in array
   If seriesarray(i) < 3 Then      'if below 3, red
    c.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf seriesarray(i) >= 3 And seriesarray(i) < 4 Then     'if between 3-4, yellow
    c.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    ElseIf seriesarray(i) >= 4 Then      'if 4 or above, green
    c.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Interior.Color = vbGreen
   End If
Next i
```

[reference for changing bar colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849488/excel-vba-changing-bar-chart-color-for-a-data-point-based-on-point-value)