# Using VBA to change bar color based on ID value in array

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements, data-visualization

I am creating a series of column graphs that show performance for each ID on one metric, but would like to highlight the columns which belong top performers on another, related metric. I do not have the data for the related metric, only a list (in Excel, on the same sheet) of IDs which are top performers.

Conditional formatting makes it easy enough to highlight the IDs that are contained in the list of top performers, but I would also like to change the color of those IDs' columns in the column chart without manually clicking to change each one.

This code  (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486186/changing-bar-colors-using-vba-based-on-category-label?lq=1) valuable thread) seems like it should be able to do what I am looking for, but I'm not familiar enough with VBA to understand how to put an array within an if condition or to apply it to all charts within a worksheet/workbook.

```
Dim c As Chart
Dim s As Series
Dim iPoint As Long
Dim nPoint As Long

Set c = ActiveChart
Set s = c.SeriesCollection(1)

nPoint = s.Points.Count
For iPoint = 1 To nPoint
    If s.XValues(iPoint) = "avg" Then
        s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next iPoint
```

I'm a Stata/SAS programmer and not overly familiar with VBA, but am confident that something like

```
local list=R26C2:R26C12

foreach worksheet in (all worksheets) {    
    foreach bar in (all_graphs of &worksheet) { 
        color &bar=blue if id in(&list) 
    }
}
```

should not be giving me as much trouble as I'm having trying to do this in VBA. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested)

```
Dim rngTP As Range
Set rngTP = Range("A1:A10") 'for example

nPoint = s.Points.Count
For iPoint = 1 To nPoint
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(s.XValues(iPoint), rngTP, 0)) Then
        s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
Next iPoint
```