# Find graph with data and change color of bars based on data in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to create a program that will:

1. cycle through all my slides and find slides that contain Chart(s), these charts are not linked to any worksheet.
2. Chart must contain data and will be of `ChartType = xlColumnClustered` or `ChartType(51)` Like in the bellow picture.
3. If it has data then look at the numbers and change the colors of each bar according to the graph below (>=6.0 then Red, <=8.0 then Blue, 6.0<= x >=8.0 then Purple)

I have tried searching through every Expression in the Locals window of the debugger to see if I could find any difference between a graph with data and a graph that has no data. I found nothing. I'm not sure how I would be able to differentiate between a slide with data and one without.

I also don't know how I would be able to access the data in the Chart to apply the colors.

Any help would be appreciated in how to handle this.

Thank you!

[image: ChartColors]

Comment: what type of an object is the chart? .... is it a picture?

Comment: @jsotola no it's a regular chart. You can right click it to edit data etc..  I'm not sure how else to define it other than `ChartType = xlColumnClustered` I could find out though if you know what I need to look for in Locals.

Comment: @jsotola I believe it's ChartType(51)

Comment: are you able to select individual bars in powerpoint?

Comment: @jsotola I can do it manually yes. You have to click the graph, click the bars and it selects all of them, then you click on the individual bar you want.

Answer (score 1):

i recorded a macro in excel of changing bar colors and tweaked it

there actually is a spreadsheet in powerpoint that feeds data to each chart in powerpoint

```
Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart.ChartData.Workbook.activesheet
```

you will have to read data from the worksheet to decide the colors for the bars, i think

here is the color changer

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    ' recorded in excel and modified

    Dim chrt As Chart
'   Set chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart                 ' excel object
    Set chrt = Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Chart

    chrt.ClearToMatchStyle
    chrt.ChartStyle = 203
    chrt.ChartStyle = 340
    chrt.ChartStyle = 333
    chrt.ChartStyle = 399

    chrt.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

    Dim fsc As FullSeriesCollection
    Set fsc = chrt.FullSeriesCollection

    With fsc(1).Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .Transparency = 0.5
        .Solid
    End With

    With fsc(1).Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With

    With fsc(2).Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

    With fsc(3).Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

    With fsc(3).Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With

    With fsc(1).Points(1).Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0.6299999952
        .Solid
    End With

    With fsc(1).Points(1).Format.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        .Transparency = 0.0500000119
        .Weight = 5
        .Style = msoLineThickBetweenThin
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this! So I searched through the Locals one more time and I actually found the data from my chart in there. The data is stored in two spots that I could find: `shpe.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value2` and in here `shpe.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.CurrentRegion.Worksheet.UsedRange.Value2` https://imgur.com/a/sqFKp. I'm really not sure how I would work with those to make my goal come alive. Do you know if there's an easier way to search Locals? If I can some how search for a value in locals, it may lead me to another path

Comment: i use the watch window, because you can put something like `shpe.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet` in there and then you do not have a long object tree to contend with .... it is excel stuff, so you can use `shpe.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.ActiveSheet.range("a1")`

Comment: I figure it out and posted below @jsotola . Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486186/changing-bar-colors-using-vba-based-on-category-label) helped me figure out what I needed to do, coupled with some of the logic posted here by @jsotola. This is the PowerPoint version of those two and does exactly what was needed in the original question.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub colorGraph()

    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shpe As Shape
    Dim pres As Object
    Dim nPoint As Long
    Dim iPoint As Long
    Dim c As Chart
    Dim s As Series

    Set pres = ActivePresentation

    For Each sld In pres.Slides
        For Each shpe In sld.Shapes

        Set s = shpe.Chart.SeriesCollection(1) 

        If Not shpe.HasChart Then GoTo nxtShpe
        If Not shpe.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered Then GoTo nxtShpe
        If s.DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0%" Or s.DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0.0%" Or s.DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%" Then GoTo nxtShpe

            nPoint = s.Points.Count

            For iPoint = 1 To nPoint
                If s.Values(iPoint) >= 8 Then
                    s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                ElseIf s.Values(iPoint) < 8 And s.Values(iPoint) >= 2 Then
                    s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                ElseIf s.Values(iPoint) < 2 And s.Values(iPoint) > 0 Then
                    s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
                End If
            Next iPoint            

nxtShpe:

        Next shpe
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: you can shorten your code by not defining `c` and using `Set s = shpe.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)`

Comment: @jsotola Thank you! I made the change. I had it in there because this is my actual code: https://pastebin.com/kx0qBC67 Do you have any suggestions for this?